# Oracle CASE STATEMENT WITH SUM

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I'm having trouble return the correct information with my select statement

table:

```
name1  | name2  | amount
------ | ------ | --------
Fred   | Fred   | 10
Bob    | Fred   | 15
Sam    | Sam    | 100
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
        CASE WHEN name1 <> name2 THEN name2
        ELSE name1 END as name,
        SUM(amount) as amount
FROM table
GROUP BY???
```

What I would like to see as a result:

```
name  | amount
----- | ------
Fred  | 25
Sam   | 100
```

I've tried using a group by and receive errors saying this is not a GROUP BY expression.  If I don't use a group by I receive the error not a single-group group function.  Is this type of query possible?

Comment: If no NULL is allowed in `name1` and `name2` then it seems you are overcomplicating things; the result is always equal to `name2`. The only exception is if either `name1` or `name2` is NULL (if that is even allowed). So: Can  you have NULL in either column?

Comment: In any case, you can GROUP BY the exact same CASE expression as you have in SELECT. (Unfortunately you cannot use the NAME alias, since that is only created after the GROUP BY is processed).

Comment: there is a null chance.  I tried to simply the table, query for the question.

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY clause has to evaluate to the same thing as your select clause did. Do this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN name1 <> name2 THEN name2 ELSE name1 END as calc_name,
    SUM(amount) as amount
FROM table
GROUP BY CASE WHEN name1 <> name2 THEN name2 ELSE name1 END
```

Also, `name` is a reserved keyword, so I modified that alias slightly.

Comment: I tried this and got this error: Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: That's telling me it can't find the field you are trying to group which means you've probably got a typo somewhere in there, either in the SELECT clause or the GROUP BY clause. Comb over the typing carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
SELECT ename,SUM(amount) amount FROM (
SELECT 
        CASE WHEN name1 <> name2 THEN name2
        ELSE name1 END as ename,
        amount
FROM table)
GROUP BY ename
```